# Erro Iframe não carregando no Mobile (celular)

Tags: wordpress, mobile, http, iframe, https

Estou tendo problema em visualizar iframe somente nos dispositivos mobile (no dev tools simulando celular funciona okay, a situação é a seguinte:

- Site em wp
- Plugin Really Simple SSL instalado (fiz testes com ele
  ativado e desativado)
- São 3 páginas diferentes com 3 links de iframe diferentes, 1 com o link em http e 2 com o link em https
- O site tem tem as páginas com o iframes tem links em https
- Erro no carregamento do iframe: link indisponível ou pode ter sido movido permanentemente para outro endereço web
- ao acessar os links https sem usar o iframe pelo Celular os links https dão erro de certificado, e ao acessar o link http ele carrega normalmente, mas todos dão o mesmo erro no iframe mobile, no desktop os links acessados sem iframe abrem normalmente.

Comment: Está com cara de cache. WP, navegadores mobile. Limpou os caches?

Comment: sim plugin de cache desativado e navegador limpo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os problemas eram o seguinte:

1) páginas https não podem ter links no iframe com http (uma das 3 páginas tinha link http).

2) o certificado do link https do iframe era inválido, e desta forma no mobile ele não funcionava. Meu antivirus estava forçando os https nos links quando eu acessava pelo computador e por isso parecia okay, mas na realidade deveria estar dando o erro de certificado inválido.

Comment: Boa. Pode aceitar sua própria resposta como a correta.